# how to group by and sum in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I read [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068926/rails-3-group-by-and-sum) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961479/rails-activerecord-friendly-code-from-a-complex-join-sum-and-group-query) but I am still having some implementation problems.

In am trying to extract all costs that belongs to a user within a certain trip and sum their values based on their type(exchange_id).
For example, a user can add a cost of 5$ , another cost of 10$ and a third cost of 50euro. I am trying to get [15$,50euro]

I have the following code `@trip.costs.where(user_id: current_user).group("exchange_id"))`, but I don't know how to go from here and extract just the cost's value and sum it

Thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
@costs = @trip.costs.where(user_id: current_user).group("exchange_id"))
@costs_sum = @costs.sum('the_field_you_want_to_sum_by')
=> { "exchange_id_1" => sum_1, ... }
```

PS: there is a typo.

Comment: I am getting `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: excahnge_id: SELECT SUM("costs"."value") AS sum_value, excahnge_id AS excahnge_id FROM "costs"  WHERE "costs"."trip_id" = ? AND "costs"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY excahnge_id`
added my cost db schema to my post

Comment: maybe because the typo? `exchange` instead of `excahnge`

Answer (score 1):

```
@trip.costs
     .where(user_id: current_user)
     .group("exchange_id")
     .sum(:the_field_you_want_to_sum_by)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review your answer and add a textual description. Code-only answers are generally not accepted on this site.

Comment: yet the accepted answer has 20 vote ups and no comment about code-only answers @alelom :facepalm:

Comment: Which is and remains a sub-optimal practice that should be pointed out. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers @53c